# How to use regex in Java to remove something from the name?

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning Regex in Java and I receive a String name from a service. The String could be in this form:

```
"Dl Frank Joseph", 
"Dna Jane XXX", 
"Dra XXX YYY", 
"Dr XXX YYY",
"XXX YYY".
```

So if the name is `"XXX YYY"` it will remain the same, but if the name contains "Dl", "Dna", "Dra", "Dr" then I should delete this word and remain only the name "XXX YYY".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex, `^(?i)(Dl|Dna|Dra|Dr)\\s+`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                "Dl Frank Joseph", 
                "Dna Jane XXX", 
                "Dra XXX YYY", 
                "Dr XXX YYY", 
                "XXX YYY"
            ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^(?i)(Dl|Dna|Dra|Dr)\\s+", "")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Frank Joseph
Jane XXX
XXX YYY
XXX YYY
XXX YYY
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iH10zw/1):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```java
String s = "Dna Jane XXX";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(Dna|Dra|Dr) ", ""));
```